# How to create a dynamic view in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, dynamic-view

I want to create a dynamic_view using a stored procedure for the following scenario.

Table1 has two columns (id, name), and it has the following three records.

```
id|name
-------
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
```

Table2 has four columns (id, date, table1_id, value) that stores values for table1 records as following:

```
id | date    |table1_id | value
------------------------------ 
1  | 2024-1-1| 1         | 2.4
2  | 2024-1-1| 2         | 2.5
3  | 2024-1-1| 3         | 2.1
4  | 2024-1-2| 2         | 2
5  | 2024-1-2| 3         | 2.3
```

Now, I want a stored procedure to create a view dynamically that has four columns (id, date, a, b, c) based on table1 records for columns and their records should be based on table2 data. this id should be auto-incremental. like the following

```
id | date    |a   | b   | c
----------------------------
1  | 2024-1-1|2.4 | 2.5 |2.1
2  | 2024-1-2|null| 2   |2.3
```

Your support is highly appreciate it.

Comment: it is called dynamic pivot

Comment: Thank you Bill for your reply, I will read about it.

Comment: Thanks again Bill, yes I solved the problem using the pivot table.
would you please help me in solving this dynamic pivot problem as well? it is related to this one but a little bit tougher

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78234874/mysql-how-to-solve-this-problem-using-dynamic-pivot